# Zend Framework using IBM's DB2 and creating a standard connection in the application.ini file

Tags: zend-framework, db2, db2-connect, db2-400

DB2 uses XML files as its basis for database tables, and I have been having a very difficult time finding any good references or examples of creating a standard connection to the database via the application.ini file. There are some examples from earlier versions using different connectors, but non that I could find that used the pdo_ibm adapter.
Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Should be the same as any other database server:

```
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_IBM"
resources.db.params.host = "your.database.host"
resources.db.params.dbname = "database_name"
resources.db.params.username = "username"
resources.db.params.password = "password"
```

Comment: Soaica,
I thought the same thing, but the database has a couple of extra parameters that I don't know how to add to the application.ini script.

Comment: This is the script I'm trying to convert in to a standard application.ini zend_db connection:
`
require_once 'Zend/Db/Adapter/Db2.php'; 

$config = array( 
                'dbname'   => '*LOCAL', 
                'username' => '', 
                'password' => '', 
                'os'=>'i5', 
                'driver_options'=> array("i5_commit" =>DB2_I5_TXN_READ_UNCOMMITTED, 
                                            "autocommit"=>DB2_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF, 
                                            "i5_lib"=>'WEBLIB')); `

Comment: My initial question was not well worded, although I received an answer almost immediately, it was not at all what I was looking for. After posting a comment to my question, the code in my comment was difficult to read. I decided to ask the question again, changed the wording and posted the code I was looking to convert.